# Using child-process to call python inside node.js in heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I have a node.js application in which I have called a Python file using child process as

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
```

I have sent some arguments to python file and the python returns data using **Print** statement back to node.js

It works fine in local and when i deployed the application to Heroku. The pythons **print** statement is not getting displayed in node.js service.

Is there any thing has to be set in heroku to call the subprocess. Please help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance